# XCode 8 bitcode compatibility

Tags: ios, xcode, compatibility, bitcode

I noticed an issue with the new XCode 8, that makes it impossible to archive on XCode 7 with bitcode.
So for example if I'm trying to develop a library on XCode 8, when using on Xcode 7 and enabling bitcode I'm getting this error:

Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.38.0_0' Reader: '703.0.29_0')

Is there any workaround for that when developing libraries on Xcode 8 (objective c)?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, the problem came when i add new pod library which change bitcode compress. So changing bitcode in Build Setting resolve my problem.

Note that for projects using CocoaPods you should set `ENABLE_BITCODE = NO` on both the project and the Pods container project targets.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still trying to solve this, at the end we created a new binary using Xcode 7 (You can download older versions of Xcode form [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)). There's no way to make Xcode 8 to create a build using an older version of bitcode.